# How to delete an employee at certain date on openerp 7?

Tags: python-2.7, openerp-7

I want to make an employee inactive automatically at trial date end.
below my code (forgive my for my bad english).

```
def inctivate_employee(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
    emp_id = self.browse(cr, uid, ids)[0].employee_id.resource_id.id
    the_date = self.pool.get('hr.contract').browse(cr, uid, contract_id, context=context).trial_date_end
    self.pool.get('resource.resource').write(cr, uid, emp_id, {
        'active': False,}) # here must be something define the date of the action

    return True
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a scheduled action to check for trial_date_end every day:

```
class hr_contract(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'hr.contract'

    @api.model
    def employee_end_trial(self):
        today = fields.Date.today()
        contract_obj = self.env['hr.contract']
        contracts = hr_contract.search([('trial_date_end', '=', today)])

        # Add your code here
```

Comment: Is this useful?